# Get match of two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists and i like to browse them to get the matchs and the difference
but i don't understand why my index don't reach the end of list 
there is my code:

```
recordedEvents=[u'/app//wakeup', u'/app/hdmi/state', u'/homepage/ws/view', u'/homepage//activate', u'/live//activate', u'/live//zap', u'/live/ctazap/view', u'/live/ppluspminus/zap', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//keypress', u'/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/zap', u'/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/view', u'/live/digit/zap', u'/live/noright/view', u'/live/digit/zap', u'/live/ctazap/view', u'/live/ctazap/click', u'/live/toolbox/view', u'/app//keypress', u'/live/toolbox/click', u'/isf//activate', u'/app//keypress', u'/live//activate', u'/live//zap', u'/live/ctazap/view', u'/live/ctazap/click', u'/live/toolbox/view', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//keypress', u'/app//standby', u'/app/favorites/state', u'/app/optin/state', u'/app/perso/state', u'/app/tnt/state', u'/app/hdd/state', u'/app/switches/state', u'/qos/live/', u'/trap//temperature']
expectedEvents=[u'/app//wakeup', u'/app/hdmi/state', u'/homepag/ws/view', u'/homepage//activate', u'/live//activate', u'/live//zap', u'/live/ppluspminus/zap', u'/app//keypress', u'/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/zap', u'/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/view', u'/live/digit/zap', u'/live/noright/view', u'/live/digit/zap', u'/live/toolbox/view', u'/live/toolbox/click', u'/isf//activate', u'/app//keypress', u'/live//activate', u'/live//zap', u'/live/toolbox/view', u'/live/toolbox/click', u'/app//standby', u'/app/favorites/state', u'/app/optin/state', u'/app/perso/state', u'/app/tnt/state', u'/app/hdd/state', u'/app/switches/state', u'/qos/live/', u'/trap//temperature']


indexR = 0
indexE = 0
n_expected_event=['ctazap']
 while indexR!=len(recordedEvents)-1:
if recordedEvents[indexR]==expectedEvents[indexE]:
    print "[event]"+str(expectedEvents[indexE])+" Matching OK"
    indexE+=1
    indexR+=1
else:
    for diff in n_expected_event:
        if str(diff) in str(recordedEvents[indexR]):
            print"[missing] "+str(recordedEvents[indexR])
    indexR+=1
```

there is the result:

```
[event]/app//wakeup Matching OK
[event]/app/hdmi/state Matching OK
[event]/homepage/ws/view Matching OK
[event]/homepage//activate Matching OK
[event]/live//activate Matching OK
[event]/live//zap Matching OK
[missing] /live/ctazap/view
[event]/live/ppluspminus/zap Matching OK
[event]/app//keypress Matching OK
[event]/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/zap Matching OK
[event]/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/view Matching OK
[event]/live/digit/zap Matching OK
[event]/live/noright/view Matching OK
[event]/live/digit/zap Matching OK
[missing] /live/ctazap/view
[missing] /live/ctazap/click
[event]/live/toolbox/view Matching OK
[event]/live/toolbox/click Matching OK
[event]/isf//activate Matching OK
[event]/app//keypress Matching OK
[event]/live//activate Matching OK
[event]/live//zap Matching OK
[missing] /live/ctazap/view
[missing] /live/ctazap/click
[event]/live/toolbox/view Matching OK
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` operations to do this. What you're asking for is essentially `set.intersection` and `set.difference`.

```
>>> set(recordedEvents).intersection(expectedEvents)
{'/app/optin/state',
 '/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/zap',
 '/qos/live/',
 '/live/ppluspminus/zap',
 '/live/noright/view',
 '/live/digit/zap',
 '/live//zap',
 '/homepage//activate',
 '/trap//temperature',
 '/app/tnt/state',
 '/app//standby',
 '/app/switches/state',
 '/live/toolbox/view',
 '/app/perso/state',
 '/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/view',
 '/app//wakeup',
 '/app/hdd/state',
 '/app/favorites/state',
 '/app/hdmi/state',
 '/isf//activate',
 '/app//keypress',
 '/live//activate',
 '/live/toolbox/click'}

>>> set(recordedEvents).difference(expectedEvents)
{'/live/ctazap/view',
 '/live/ctazap/click',
 '/homepage/ws/view'}
```

Then you don't need to do any iterating yourself. If you still want to print out with formatting, you can do so.

```
>>> for i in set(recordedEvents).intersection(expectedEvents):
    print('[event]{} Matching OK'.format(i))

[event]/app/optin/state Matching OK
[event]/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/zap Matching OK
[event]/qos/live/ Matching OK
[event]/live/ppluspminus/zap Matching OK
[event]/live/noright/view Matching OK
[event]/live/digit/zap Matching OK
[event]/live//zap Matching OK
[event]/homepage//activate Matching OK
[event]/trap//temperature Matching OK
[event]/app/tnt/state Matching OK
[event]/app//standby Matching OK
[event]/app/switches/state Matching OK
[event]/live/toolbox/view Matching OK
[event]/app/perso/state Matching OK
[event]/live/virtualzappinglistbanner/view Matching OK
[event]/app//wakeup Matching OK
[event]/app/hdd/state Matching OK
[event]/app/favorites/state Matching OK
[event]/app/hdmi/state Matching OK
[event]/isf//activate Matching OK
[event]/app//keypress Matching OK
[event]/live//activate Matching OK
[event]/live/toolbox/click Matching OK

>>> for i in set(recordedEvents).difference(expectedEvents):
    print('[missing] {}'.format(i))

[missing] /live/ctazap/view
[missing] /live/ctazap/click
[missing] /homepage/ws/view
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i have used list set end function intersection but this give me result not sorting for example [event]/app//wakeup Matching OK should be the match number 1